# Propulsion of an object relative to another one

Tags: python, vector, pygame

I have a player, and I have a bullet, that is being shooted by a weapon the player has. I want it so that when the bullet touch a tile, the player is being propulsed to the opposite direction, with the speed of the propulsion being distance-relative. It's not a simple task (at least for me). But here is what I would like to have.. :
[image: Idea of what I would like to have]

I first thought about using vectors. So I made this function :

```
def calculate_vector(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return x1 - x2, y1 - y2
```

This function would return me the vector the player should use to go to the opposite direction of the bullet. It does work. But, now here is my problem, I would like to have different speed/power based on the distance of the bullet. If the player is really close to the bullet, then it should be propulsed further away than if the player is 20 pixel away. Again if the player is too far away from the bullet, it should just not be propulsed.

I tried to implement that, but I just can't seem to find out how to do that. If someone has an idea, maybe just an hint of how to do that, or an explenation, it would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: You need to define your problem better.

Comment: maybe "dot product" will help https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/dot-cross-products/v/vector-dot-product-and-vector-length

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "too far"? You should specify your distances more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the position of the player relative to the position of the bullet, you could find the hypotenuse of those two values, and propel the player with different values based on how large of a value the hypotenuse is. Here's how to find the hypotenuse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

(the hypotenuse would be the length)